# Can't load js into MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, macos, mongodb

Trying to get [this project](https://github.com/DanWahlin/CustomerManager) to run locally.

NPM is installed. Mongo is running, but can't load the seed files.

Using mac OSX, my terminal output is:

```
curtiss-mbp:CustomerManager curtiss$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.7.4
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings: 
2014-08-16T18:28:54.115-0400 [initandlisten] 
2014-08-16T18:28:54.115-0400 [initandlisten] ** NOTE: This is a development version (2.7.4) of MongoDB.
2014-08-16T18:28:54.115-0400 [initandlisten] ** Not recommended for production.
2014-08-16T18:28:54.115-0400 [initandlisten] 
2014-08-16T18:28:54.115-0400 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
2014-08-16T18:28:54.115-0400 [initandlisten]

use custmgr
switched to db custmgr
load("initMongoCustData.js")
2014-08-16T18:40:33.956-0400 Error: remove needs a query
at Error ()
at DBCollection.remove (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:299:31)
at initMongoCustData.js:65:14
at (shell):1:1 at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:299
2014-08-16T18:40:33.956-0400 Error: error loading js file: initMongoCustData.js
at (shell):1:1
```

It fails to load the js into MongoDB. Am I missing something or doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Line 65](https://github.com/DanWahlin/CustomerManager/blob/master/CustomerManager/initMongoCustData.js#L65) in initMongoCustData.js should be changed from

```
db.customers.remove();
```

to

```
db.customers.remove({});
```